# Vim Regex OR in File Name Pattern on Windows

Tags: regex, vim

I'm trying to formulate a regular expression that matches the names of a set of files I would like to batch process in Vim but am finding that I cannot seem to use \| (regex OR) as expected...

Specifically, I would like to create an argument list consisting of the following files in the current directory:

```
f0148.e, f0149.e, f0150.e ... f0159.e (i.e., 12 files total)
```

The vim command I entered goes as follows:

```
:arg f01\(\(4[89]\)\|\(5[0-9]\)\).e
```

Vim completes this command without any noticeable result -- there's no message and the output from :args remains unchanged (doesn't produce the desired list of file names).

If I split up the regular expression to:
`:arg f01\(\(4[89]\)\).e` (note: leaving parenthesis here as in above full expression)
...and...

```
:arg f01\(\(5[0-9]\)\).e
```

... then `:args` produces `f0148.e f0149.e` and `f0150.e ... f0159.e` respectively (as desired).

Also, if I enter the above mentioned list of file names in a text file and use the above mentioned regular expression as a search pattern (i.e., `/f01\(\(4[89]\)\|\(5[0-9]\)\).e`), it works just as desired.

Thus, I determined that the alternation `(\|)` is somehow causing the the expression to fail. Please note that I'm using Vim on Windows 7, if this is relevant (since both backslash and pipe are valid symbols at the Windows command prompt).

A quick workaround would be to use:

```
:arg f014[89].e
:argadd f015[0-9].e
```

...but I would really like to figure out how to make the above regular expression work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please read [how to post code excerpts on Stack Exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). In short: Highlight and press CTRL-K.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out -- and so quickly, too!!

Answer (score 2):

I could suggest:

```
:let file_list = filter(split(globpath('.','**'),nr2char(10)), 'v:val =~ ''f01\(\(4[89]\)\|\(5[0-9]\)\)\.e'' ')
:execute 'args ' . join(map(file_list,'fnameescape(v:val)'),' ')
```

How this works:

- `globpath('.','**')` makes a list of all files in current directory and all subdirectories. `:help globpath()`.
- `split(..., nr2char(10))` will make a list of it, because the separator was Line Feed
- `filter(..., 'v:val =~ ''pattern'' ')` filters the list keeping only items matching pattern. `:help v:val`. Doubling single quote is escaping them inside single quote string.
- `map(..., fnameescape())` escapes all spaces and backslashes
- `join()` adds spaces between file names

If you want to make it a function you can put this into your vimrc:

```
function! ArgsPattern(pat)
  let file_list = filter(split(globpath('.','**'),nr2char(10)), 'v:val =~ ''' . substitute(a:pat,"'","''",'g') . '''')
  execute 'args ' . join(map(file_list,'fnameescape(v:val)'),' ') 
endfunction
command! -nargs=+ ArgsPattern call ArgsPattern(<q-args>)
```

And then you only have  to do:

```
:ArgsPattern f01\(\(4[89]\)\|\(5[0-9]\)\)\.e
```

Note that if there is no match, then the `execute` command inside the function evaluates to `:args` and therefore the list of your current arguments are printed.

Comment: There's a minor syntax error -- `file_list` should be `aaa` (or vise versa) but otherwise this works. It's a bit more complicated than what I was looking for but I appreciate the suggestion and the thorough explanation! This might come in handy for something else in the future.

Comment: @Mesagoma: Thanks for the feedback, you could have suggested an edit.

Comment: I'll try to remember to suggest an edit next time. Thanks for the function, alas, it doesn't appear to do the same thing as the commands you posted -- it goes into sub-folders, too. Also, it'd be nice to be able to include a path in the regular expression...

But this is sorta going into the wrong direction: **What I'm really looking for** is to make the original regular expression work with the `arg` command (perhaps by escaping the regex OR differently?) or to learn _why_ `\|` cannot be used in this context.